# Value gets lost after routing in Angular5

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am trying to get a value from the browser in forms.component.ts and use it in student.component.ts and but i loose the value after routing to student component , i have even tried to use onInit and onDestroy to keep the value but am unable to do so.

I added a dataservice.ts file to store the value of the data as buffer but still the value in browser is not being displayed and is showing undefined
Please Help!!

```js
//forms.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit , OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import {DataService} from '../dataservice';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   name = 'kanav';
   link = '';
    res: string;


  constructor(public dataservice: DataService) {
    this.newVal = this.res;
  }

  str: string;
  newVal: any;
  ngOnInit() {

  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.dataservice.link = this.res;
    this.dataservice.test = this.name;
  }
sendValues(): void {
   this.res = this.str.substring(0, this.str.length - 11) + 'embedded=true';
   console.log(this.res);
}


}
```

```js
//dataservice.ts

export class DataService {
     public link: any;
    public test: string;

}
```

```js
//student.component.ts
import { Component , OnInit , OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
// import { FormComponent } from '../form/form.component';
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {DataService} from '../dataservice';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-student',
  templateUrl: './student.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./student.component.css']
})
export class StudentComponent implements OnInit , OnDestroy {

  constructor( public sanitizer: DomSanitizer, public dataservice: DataService) { }
    finalVal: any;
    finaltest: string;
    ngOnInit() {
         this.finalVal = this.dataservice.link ;
         this.finaltest = this.dataservice.test;
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {

    }
  show() {
    console.log(this.finaltest);
    // this.finalVal = this.forms.newVal;
    // return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.link);
  //     return console.log('hi there');
    return console.log();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate your service with @Injectable(), otherwise, it may not be instantiated when you define it in the constructor. Or maybe you have different instances of it in each component

Comment: It would be really appreciated if you could tell me how to do so

Comment: Just add @Injectable() before your DataService class declaration, and add the corresponding import